# read file to bytearray adobe extendscript

Tags: extendscript

Is there a way to read a file in adobe extendscript to bytearray? I will upload 
the bytes to a rest server.

Currently, i'm using below and it is giving me binary string.
var s = file.read();

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  The JavaScript interpreter ExtendScript is based on pre-dates the typed array datatypes.  You'll have to work with the binary string.